# Big -Oh Computation (refresher help)

Tags: data-structures, big-o

Okay, so I have a midterm later today and one of the items I am reviewing is big-O. Now, I did the homework way back in the day and got 100%....but I can't find it now and I am unsure of what I am doing. Sooo could someone give me an explanation as to what I am doing wrong...and if I am doing it right...well maybe you know why I am doubting myself? 
Thanks!

Also, I remember before with my homework I was using summations, and I would work from the inside out. And when I finished each summation I used some "forumla" to calculate the highest n, and then keep that value and move on to the next summation, and so on and so forth until the summations were all completed.

Problem 1.

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sum++;
```

So, since I forgot the whole summation aspect of this, my gut instinct tell me this is O(N), because the maximum runtimes is N times...since it is just one for loop.

Problem 2.

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        sum++;
```

For this one, I "think" it is O(N^2) for the highest run time, since both loops are dependent on n, and it could maximize at N * N per if loop.

Problem 3.

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n * n; j++)
        sum++;
```

This is where I get stuck...I feel like I actually need to use the summation layout along with the formula for adding them up. The inner most loop can maximize at n*n, so n^2. On top of which, it can maximize at N again for the outermost loop...so I would guess 0(N^3).

Problem 4.

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        sum++;
```

Again, I am more lost on this one. The inner loop can maximize i times...which is dependent on i however, which is dependent on N....So...I see three maximized variables, and I am literally unsure of how to compare them to find a maximized runtime. (I really need to remember that summation setup and formula).

Same goes for the next problems, no clue where to start, and I'd rather not try to because I don't want to get the wrong thinking in my head. I am positive once I see the formula again it will instantly click, because I got it before...I just lost it somehow.
Any help appreciated!

Problem 5:

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < i * i; j++)
        for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
        sum++;
```

Problem 6:

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 1; j < i * i; j++)
        if (j % i == 0)
           for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
               sum++;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for problems 4 to 6, I would assume i j and k are all integers, unlike n which is a variable. how I would approach the problems would be:

e.g. problem 4

inner loop - iterations from 0 to (i-1), which gives us i number of iterations.

outer loop - n summations

combined - O(i * n) = O(n) since i is an integer.